# Store a C# Object into an AutoCAD entity's XRecord

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I'm trying to find a way that I can store a C# class into an AutoCAD entity as an XRecord. For example, I have the following class:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public ExampleClass(int x, int y)
    {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
    }

    #region Getters and Setters
}
```

and I create an instance of it:

```
ExampleClass objToStoreInXRecord = new ExampleClass(3, 5);
```

What is the best way to store that into an AutoCAD entity's (for example a line in the drawing) XRecord so that I could do something like this:

```
ExampleClass objRecoveredFromXRecord = GetXRecordFromEntity(Entity e)
```

Where GetXRecordFromEntity(Entity e) is a helper method I can write that takes an entity e, gets the XRecord of the object I stored earlier, and returns it.

I don't have a very good handle on how XRecord works and how XRecord relates to AutoCAD's Named Object Dictionary (NOD). [I've seen implementations](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/serialize-a-net-class-into-an-autocad-drawing-database.html) where the object to be stored in an XRecord is serialized with a binary formatter and the serialized data is stored in the entity's XRecord but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: What is it that you don't like about serializing with a binary formatter?  If it's because it's binary that's the issue, you can serialize to Json or XML instead?

Comment: I use a whole hierarchy of classes and I was hoping to avoid marking them all as serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize the object and add it to the xrecord.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use .NET Serialize is not the supported way in AutoCAD, meaning other apps will not understand that...

Check this discussion at the Autodesk Forum, it may clarify what I mean. Also, there is a small code snippet.

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/binary-serialization-to-xrecord/td-p/5601969